# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: qs is not defined"

Tags: vue.js, axios

I am trying to use qs to stringfy my data in html.
My script import like this:

```
<script src="{% static 'main/axios.min.js'%}"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/qs/6.7.0/qs.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'main/vue.js'%}"></script>
```

and my html body like this:

```
<body>
<div id="ele">
    <button v-on:click="test">testApi</button>
</div>

<script>
    var api = new Vue({
        delimiters:['${','}'],
        el: "#ele",
        methods:{
            test:function(event){
                alert("testApi")
                data = qs.stringfy({"msg":"test",'status':"started"})
                axios.post('testApi',data)
                .then(response=>{
                    alert("getData!")
                })
            }
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
```

But the button doesn't run as expected. In my chrome console, I get this:
[image: error]

It says qs is not defined, but actually I have the script up. Could you tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note this cdnjs uses Qs, not qs.

Try this.

```
data = Qs.stringify({"msg":"test",'status':"started"})
console.log(data)
```